# Passing an array as the parameter of a function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters, associative-array

This is my array

```
$sub  = array("English"=>"12","Hindi"=>"12","History"=>"12","Geography"=>"12","Mathematics"=>"12","Physics"=>"12","Chemistry"=>"12","Biology"=>"12");
```

Want to pass this entire array as the parameter of a function & want to sum up the marks(array values) using the function

```
function sum_marks($sub){--Function body--
}
```

I don't know if this is the proper syntax for passing an array to a function, help!!

Comment: Did you have a specific question? What's the problem?

Comment: To answer your question: yes, that is the syntax for doing so.

Comment: There is no magic. You say you want it done automatically ... and it would be nice if you explain that.

Comment: You should clarify whether your question is "How do I pass an array as an argument to a function?" or "How do I sum the values of an array?"

Comment: Sorry 4 the confusion, actually I want to pass my array $sub as an argument 2 a function sum_marks, n then want to sum the values of the array inside d function, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will create a function that has a reference to your array. When you change the array you can call the product of the function, and it will recalculate the sum.

```
$array = ['English' => '12', 'Swedish' => '12'];

function arraySumCb(&$subject) {
  return function () use (&$subject) {
    return array_sum($subject);
  };
}

$sum = arraySumCb($array);
echo $sum(); // 24
$array['Swedish'] = '15';
echo $sum(); // 27
$array['Swedish'] = '10';
echo $sum(); // 22
```

Edit: This is how I would do it.

```
$array = ['English' => '12', 'Swedish' => '12'];

class SumMarks {
  private $_subject;
  public function __construct(array &$subject = []) {
    $this->_subject = &$subject;
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return "" . array_sum($this->_subject);
  }
}

$sum = new SumMarks($array);

echo $sum; // 24

$array['Swedish'] = '10';

echo $sum; // 22
```

Edit: Proper use of PHP anonymous functions

Comment: There's no need to use global here, really.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily fancy way to get the sum of array values. "_[array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) — Calculate the sum of values in an array_"

Comment: @localheinz Really, the global was needed. But the reference was not. Updated the answer with proper use of anonymous functions.

Comment: @BizzyBob True(ish), Makes no sense now when the question has changed. But when it said "... so if anytime I wish to change the number of the subjects, I can just change the array and the sum will change automatically".
I think it was a fair question (learning purposes).

Comment: That makes sense :-)

Answer (score 3):

Is this you are looking for?

```
$mySum = array_sum($sub);
```

Comment: The 'ol shot in the dark, huh?

Comment: Hahaha something like this. The question wasn't easy to understand, but that is what I got between the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the appropriate syntax for passing an array as an argument to a function.

However, you might consider adding a type declaration for the `$sub` argument:

```
function sum_marks(array $sub)
{
    return array_sum($sub);
}
```

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a certain type at call time. If the given value is of the incorrect type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a [TypeError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) exception.

However, you really probably just want to use `array_sum()` directly.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: I'm simply trying to pass my array $sub to the function sum_marks n sum the values of my array inside the function, now my array has 8 elements( key=>value), next time if I add one extra element or reduce one, the function will recalculate accordingly

Comment: You mean, when you add or remove element to the array, the function should automatically calculate the sum again?

Comment: Yup...that's what im looking for

Comment: And this without invoking the function?

Comment: Not sure if that's possible, if  I can pass the array to my function n somehow manage to count the nmber of elements(keys) using loop, n then sum the values, otherwise hv to think another way out. Thank you!

Comment: The other question should be: is it necessary?

Answer (score -1):

I dont understand your question, please ask with specific question. .
But maybe this what are you want :

```
function sum_marks($sub){
$result = array_sum($sub);
retrun $result; 
}
```